# Android App for Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm not sure what language android uses but I'm doing some reading on it now. 
All I want is a push notification that will tell me if I am logged off facebook. Nothing special. I've never tried to make anything for android or iphone or any of that. 
This issue is from issues like, maybe someone doesn't like a post you made and it gets reported and facebook logs you out and your automatic posts no longer work because you're logged out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for accomplishing this? Maybe what language it would best be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Learn JAVA(its a must) - that's the language you will use in Eclips ADT.

2) Download Eclips [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). and install.

3) [Android development Training.](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

4) [Documentaion](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

5) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I've been meaning to learn JAVA but got sidetracked with php and JS. Again, thank you!

Comment: it will take hardwork, patience, practice and interest to achive the same. all the best! mark ans correct if it was helpful :)

Comment: I've been waiting for it to let me lol, which download do you recommend? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: Download from the android develper's website http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I give you a second thumbs up! Thank you!